# How to add SSL support to Python?

Tags: python, ssl

On Ubuntu 14.04, I installed Python 3. Now that I am programming with it, I had a problem with Python and I am told that the error occurred because I did not install Python with SSL support.

Is it possible to add SSL support to Python without needing to uninstall and reinstall Python from the start?

I ask this question following the comment on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247424/how-to-send-post-data-from-python-to-php-scripts-with-basic-http-authentication).

Comment: What are you doing, and who told you what? Please [edit] your post to quote them and include code if relevant.

Comment: @Oli Look to the last comment of my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247424/how-to-send-post-data-from-python-to-php-scripts-with-basic-http-authentication)

Comment: if you try to install ssl module with "easy_install pyopenssl" ?

Comment: @Kabyle Martijn Pieters [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247424/how-to-send-post-data-from-python-to-php-scripts-with-basic-http-authentication#comment39366402_25247470) that SSL is possibly missing which is not the same as OpenSSL. OpenSSL is just contains an implementation of SSL. I have adjusted your post accordingly. You really do not want to write your own HTTPS library building on top of SSL as there are plenty ways to burn yourself. See also the fat warning on https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yes, you are right, but I asked this because OpenSSL (as you said) is the implementation of SSL, and for Ubuntu it is a good thing to use OpenSSL, that is why my question is asked this way. But you can edit if you see a better way to do  express the idea. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python3 in Ubuntu has SSL support. You can simply test by running `python3` and then firing of a couple of commands:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('https://askubuntu.com').read()
```

A ton of HTML will fall out the other side. SSL is working.

As a more general answer to your SO question, I'd strongly consider looking at the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It can be installed with the `python3-requests` package and makes all the stuff you're doing *much* easier and more logical. Boils your entire thing down to:

```
import requests
requests.post(
    url,
    auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'),
    data={"Hello": "There"},
    headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)
```

I agree that it's largely preference (you can do everything you want without it) but it makes for easier to understand code.

Comment: @Dan9er the print is unnecessary from an interactive shell. Even from a non-interactive setting, if SSL isn't baked in or is otherwise broken, it'll barf out an error unless you explicitly catch it.