# Is Python 3.5 built without SSL support on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, python3, ssl

My question is simple: Is python 3.5.1-3 built without SSL support on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

```
root@intranet:/opt/letsencrypt# /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import HTTPSHandler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'HTTPSHandler'
>>>
```

Other Information:

```
root@intranet:/opt/letsencrypt# dpkg-query -l 'python3*' | grep ssl
ii  python3-openssl               0.15.1-2build1          all          Python 3 wrapper around the OpenSSL library

root@intranet:/opt/letsencrypt# dpkg-query -l 'libssl*' | grep dev
ii  libssl-dev:amd64  1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.2 amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl-doc        1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.2 all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
```

Answer (score 3):

Python3 in the repositories **is compiled with SSL support**.  The error you get is because `HTTPSHandler` is a third party Python module and is not part of the standard Python library.

You will need to install that module with `python3 pip install` most likely to get it to be recognized by your Python3 interpreter.

---

You can verify HTTPS/SSL support in Python3 with the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlopen('https://askubuntu.com').read()
```

It will spit out a bunch of HTML but the fact it returns a ton of HTML indicates it has SSL support.

(thanks to [Oli's answer to a similar but different question](https://askubuntu.com/a/510316/10616) for the code snippet.)